# Can you embed a WebKit Plugin into a Cococa Application without using a WebView

Tags: cocoa, webkit

Is it possible to embed a webkit plugin into an application directly (bypassing a WebView)?

Specifically I'm trying to embed Silverlight into a Cocoa application.  If the silverlight .xap is contained in a html file and that is displayed with a WebView then MouseOver events in the silverlight application aren't called.  This appears to be related to this bug http://openradar.appspot.com/6652223 - so am I able to just directly embed the silverlight plugin into my cocoa view?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find out the answer to my specific question, but I found out what was causing my problem (and it wasn't related to the bug that I had listed), it had to do with not executing things on the UI thread.